# Is there a way to fold my code by default in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have a lot of method in my classes and I find that folding them to the method line is a great way of keeping on top of where stuff is in the class file. However, if I close my project and reopen it the folds are no longer there. I would like to know is there a way of setting methods to be folded by default or getting XCode to remember what you have folded?

Comment: I does open with files in closed state.

Comment: can you qualify that @thatzprem? I have 40 methods and all of them are expanded everytime I open the project, if you know a way of setting it to keep them rolled up (folded) please share.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen an option like this, even in the preferences file for XCode. File a [Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) requesting it.

Comment: that Radar link took me to a bug reporter, I don't think this is a bug reporter, should I put in under Feature New?

Comment: The RADAR bug reporter is where apple devs can file bugs and feature requests. This would definitely qualify as a feature request